# Wordpress and Drupal SSO/Single Sign On

Tags: mysql, wordpress, drupal, single-sign-on, sign

I've made my front end website in Wordpress and this is fine for me, i want to create the member/staff area in Drupal as it has more functionality with Google docs and Mediawiki.

I was wondering if its possible for me to share logins between both sites, so if i register a user on wordpress, they will be able to login on the Drupal site aswell?

Comment: Yeah i have, the thing is im wanting to create an internal site for my company using drupal. So i dont want the public to be able to login or register.

Comment: That's easily done in Drupal , you can have fine grain control over who does what. It's pretty easy to stop anonymous users from either login in or registering

Comment: even with openid? i want something where staff can login and have access, but no one else is allowed to register or navigate through the pages.

Comment: @Namenone I'm thinking of taking the same approach for a community website. Would like to know about your experience and see if it actually worked having wordpress in front and Drupal in back. Have you shared it somewhere in a blog post or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenId would be a way to do it , other than that it should be possible to write a function to retrieve the Wordpress users info from the database and create corresponding users in Drupal. The function would then be called whenever a new user is created.  Both platforms are well documented, so it shouldn't be too difficult to work out.

Now, I know you made your point clear about using both Wordpress & Drupal , but it does sound a bit like overkill knowing that whatever you can do in Wordpress should easily be possible in Drupal... but I digress ;)

Comment: I do agree that Drupal is as good if not better than wordpress. My main site (For consumers) runs wordpress as it will feature a blog etc (plus there are a load of plugins which i can use instead of having to script stuff from scratch). The Drupal part will only be for staff, due to easy integration with mediawiki and google docs. Do you have any idea if wordpress and drupal store user data in a similar way? Because if so, i can just import the tables from one to another ?

Comment: I haven't used Wordpress in a while but I wouldn't be surprised if the data was stored differently. This being said , as mentioned earlier, it shouldnt be too difficult to query the Wordpress database and format the result for Drupal insertion. You should go to drupal.org and check the database documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [saml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) as your solution for single sign on and provisioning. Is standard and many companies uses it.

Check [simplesamlphp](http://simplesamlphp.org) , an open source software with good documentation, active project and nice comunity.

Exists plugins to easy add saml support to [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSAMLAuth), [Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/376470) and [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplesamlphp-authentication/).

Also google has saml support and [simplesaml let easy handler it](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/trunk/simplesamlphp-googleapps)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out modules that can allow you to do so. For example, I found this Drupal [OAuth Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth_login_oauth2) module and this [OAuth Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-oauth-20-server/) plugin in WordPress that helped me with my use case.